# How does sprintf() protect against SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have heard that `sprintf()` protects against SQL injection. Is it true? If so, how?

Why people are recommending to write query like this:

```
$sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 = %s AND COL2 = %s',$col1,$col2);
```

Comment: *Which* people recommend such a thing?

Comment: What you probably mean is prepared statements, which is a different topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

sprintf won't protect you! It only replaces the `%s`

you must mysql_real_escape_string so:

```
$sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 = "%s" AND COL2 = "%s"',
mysql_real_escape_string($col1),
mysql_real_escape_string($col2));
```

is safer injection

note: I suggest you take a look at [PDO](http://be.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), it is what I like to use for DBconections and queries

Comment: @beardthatcode
mysqli_real_escape_string should be used instead.
The mysql_ * functions have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 and have been removed since PHP 7.

And by the way. mysqli also supports prepared statements.

Personally, I would recommend that all incoming variables like $ _GET, $ _POST, $ _REQUEST be run through a web application firewall (WAF). I have also read here that $_FILES should be checked, butI don't understand why this superglobal could contain malcious content.

Comment: Also I always enclose table and row names in backticks.
Therefore the statement becomes more readable.
Also with using backticks you don't have to worry about reserved names.
So you could for example  name a sorting row ORDER without getting an error.
Without you will get one.

Answer (score 9):

That doesn't do any protection. Using `sprintf` makes for more readable code then dropping in and out of a string to run `mysql_real_escape_string` over each of the variables … but that example doesn't escape the variables at the end so that advantage is lost.

If you want decent protection, use something that provides [bound parameters](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Comment: Ooops. `stupid_overlong_not_fake_function_names` are too easy to introduce typos to at this time of the morning. :)

Answer (score 3):

Using sprintf might protect against SQL injection for numeric fields:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = %i", $col1);
```

By using sprintf in this way, you can be sure that $col1 will be converted to an integer--although it might generate an error or warning, if it's not truly an integer.

The proper way to protect against SQL injection is to check all of your input values, and do escaping.  But that's much more thoroughly covered in other questions, so I'm not going to go into detail here.

Comment: But with integers, you'd not have to use special precautions anyway.

Comment: Sure you do... What if the user-input "integer" looks like this:  "; DROP TABLE users;"?

Comment: Then it's not an integer, very simple. I did not say you could drop type checking.

Comment: You said "no special precautions"--I would consider type checking a precaution. In any case, using sprintf is a silly way to try to protect against SQL injection for any data.

Comment: Or simply $col1=$col1+0; before using it.

Comment: or shorter $col1 += 0;

Answer (score 1):

It obviously doesn't and if you've actually read that in a book or tutorial you should automatically discard it for future reference.

However, it can be a practical way to generate output that needs further processing. Please compare:

```
echo '<p>Hello, <strong></strong>' . htmlspecialchars($name) . ', welcome to ' . htmlspecialchars($place). '</p>';

echo sprintf('<p>Hello, <strong>%s</strong>, welcome to %s</p>',
    htmlspecialchars($name),
    htmlspecialchars($place)
);
```

Same applies to other kind of output, such as SQL code, but of course you still need to do something to input in order to make it safe: sprintf() is just a regular string function that's unaware of SQL and databases.

Please note that bind parameters use a similar syntax:

```
// Fictional DB abstraction layer
$sql = 'SELECT foo_id
    FROM foo
    WHERE name=:name AND status=:status';
$params = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'status' => $status,
);
$result = $db->run($sql, $params);
```

That's why I particularly find easier to use those DB libraries that provide this syntax, such as PDO.