# Why is this a bad MYSQL query in PHP?

Tags: php, android, mysql

Is this a bad mysql query i used in php?

```
$tablenamep = $_POST["tablenamep"];
$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `$tablenamep` WHERE number=9");
```

So when i try to fetch the result using:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
```

There is an sql injection error :
**mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given**

I have read several questions and answers regarding this error, but my question is why is the query returning a boolean, when i have even added a value to $tablenamep variable. I added the value to the variable from my android app using this code :

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tablenamep", msg));
```

The codes are working and there aren't any errors, but my android app is crashing when i try to get the result of the php.  How can i solve this! (NOTE : there is nothing wrong in my android app, i've thoroughly checked it)

Why is this a bad query? What can i do for the Query to not return a boolean, and return the actual value?

Comment: because you are **passing php variable directly to the query**.. use **parameter binding**...

Comment: I see a lot of people use `\`` on table names and columns and 99% of the time they just do it because they don't know any better. The only time it's required is when the variable might be a [mysql reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: Please secure that query from sql injections!

Comment: @NishantSolanki, parameter binding wouldn't work since the it is a table.   Table and column names won't work with parameter binding, however other steps can be taken to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: OP:  The boolean returned is false meaning the query itself is bad.  Test the query independently from PHP, echo it out: `echo "SELECT * FROM $tablenamep WHERE number=9";`

Comment: it works if i dont use the variable $tablenamep and if i use a table named "mytable". Why cant i add the variable $tablenamep in the query. Why does it have to return a boolean? :(

Comment: @Devon yeah you are right.. may be using `printf` function with `%s` can do it...

Comment: @NishantSolanki Show me an example!

Comment: @user3522805 please refer this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646731/how-sprintf-protects-again-sql-injection

Comment: Please use prepared statements.

Comment: please see answer below - your problem is that your actually sql query is failing - if it fails it returns FALSE which is throwing your error - this is most likely caused by your posted data being incorrect - try  echoing it out as suggested and you might find a problem with the data (most likely something mis-typed and it hasn't been posted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your `$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM` $tablenamep `WHERE number=9");`
returns fails.

As what stated [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp) in **TECHNICAL DETAILS TABLE**

> For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, or EXPLAIN queries it will
> return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries it will
> return TRUE. FALSE on failure

mysqli_fetch_assoc() function needs mysqli_result but the query fails that why it returns boolean instead of object.

Comment: So what should i do? Solution??

Comment: Provide me the solution to the problem you said!

Answer (score 0):

You will find that your query has 'failed'

Insert the bit of code below

```
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

just above this line

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
```

and you will find it dies at the script there.

Odds are that your posted value has a problem with it - echo out your posted value and see if it contains any `'` or `"` etc. etc.