# Multiple entries in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can I store multiple entries in SQL in one field?
For example in field phone I want to let users enter more phones like private, home, business etc.

Any hellp on how can I create trat form and how to store data in sql?

I guess I can store them using serialize() function in php but how to make a form and collect that information?

```
Form:

Home Phone: 321321333
Other: 333213213
Add Another
```

Also I would like to make that they can edit name field so if users want to put Home Tel instead of Home Phone or Pager instead Other.

ANY HELP? PLEASE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `serialize()`, like you said. However, for a working add another button you need JavaScript. Here is a form:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
    <div id="phoneNumbers">
        <input type="text" value="home phone">: <input type="text" name="0-value" value="(xxx)xxx-xxxx">
    </div>
    <button onclick="addAnother();">Add Another Phone Number</button>
    <input type="submit>
</form>
```

Here is the javascript (put in head tag of your page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nums=0;
    function addAnother(){

        document.getElementById('phoneNumbers').innerHTML+='<input type="text" name="'+++nums+'-name">: <input type="text" name="'+nums+'-value">';

    }
</script>
```

Here is action.php:

```
<?php
$arrayOfNums=array();
foreach($_POST as $curVal){
    array_push($arrayOfNums,$curVal);
}
$serializedArray=serialize($arrayOfNums);
#now do whatever code you have to add serializedArray to your database. It is a string, so this is easy.
?>
```

Now you have a serialized array in your database. Just `unserialize()` it and you have an array like this, alternating between name and value: 'home tel','(324)444-4356','work tel','(444)546-5678' etc. This is untested, tell me if it fails.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do that in php if a have more things on that page except phone. So how can I set controller on if($this->request->is('post') to do that array serialize only if the phone values are saving?

Answer (score 3):

You ***do not*** store multiple values in a single field. You need a normalized structure that will allow for multiple phone numbers. A 1:n relationship would be appropriate here.

```
user (userId PK)
userPhone (userId FK, phoneType, phoneNumber (userId, phoneType PK))
```

Comment: Any help on how can I do that?

Comment: @Miskone I would recommend you read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105/what-datatype-should-be-used-for-storing-phone-numbers-in-sql-server-2005). While it talks about SQL Server, it still applies here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` for saving and accessing data.

**For saving.**

```
$phone_number = array("Home Phone" => "321321333", "Other" => "333213213");
$encoded = json_encode($phone_number);
```

**For accessing.**

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$decoded = json_decode( $result['phone_number_mysql_fields'] );
```

You can use the PHP <kbd>[**`serialize`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)</kbd> function to store arrays and objects in MySQL

Comment: why not just serialize() instead of json_encode? serialize is native to PHP, json is from javascript

Comment: How would you go about searching for a phone number?

Comment: @Markasoftware i have also edited answer and mentioned serialize too.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk for that read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116419/mysql-select-query-within-a-serialized-array

Comment: @DipeshParmar It clearly states that you *shouldn't* serialize it and store it in a normalized fashion.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk yes but it says when you need to perform other things like sorting etc

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk and also you did not mentioned that you need searching on stored data so i answered it accordingly.