# Cutting out a string from another string

Tags: mysql

I am selecting multiple records, containing strings having this form:

```
...s:12:"out_trade_no";s:7:"TRANSACTION_ID";s:11:"notify_time";s:19:...
```

What I am trying to get is only the TRANSACTION_ID from between the repeating `s:7:s"` and `";s:`.

How do I do that? Substring function takes only one argument while I need two here.

Comment: Nested substrings?

Comment: That looks like the result of a  `serialize()` so try to `unserialize()` it [Check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: RiggsFolly is speaking of PHP's `serialize()` and `unserialize()` functions.

Comment: I just need to cut this numer out of this string in mysql select.

Comment: Unnecessarily complicated and prone to mistakes. Do it properly in PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just have access to phpmyadmin only. No php environment configurated.

Comment: Then you have a lot of painful text manipulation to do. OUCH!

Comment: You're trying to *parse a serialized php object string in MySQL*. Your favorite search engine will show you some suggestions. @RiggsFolly is right: this is hard and error-prone. But you may be able to get it to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116419/mysql-select-query-within-a-serialized-array