# Select mysql with php for mail into serialize array

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

With an input of `info@test.com` how can I select a record in the database with the below value?

```
a:4:{s:4:"nome";s:14:"Napoleon";s:5:"email";s:23:"info@test.com";s:19:"conferma_condizioni";s:1:"1";s:2:"ip";s:12:"84.33.92.109";}
```

I have tried:

```
$sql_mail = "SELECT * FROM wp_cf7db WHERE data REGEXP '.*'info@test.com';s:[0-9]+:'2'.*'"
```

Comment: Although possibly not a direct duplicate, this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4116419/231316

Comment: Please edit the question with any code that you tried.

Comment: I have to check in php if that mail exists in the database inside that code

Comment: I would think a `LIKE` would be sufficient then: `SELECT * FROM wp_cf7db WHERE data LIKE '%info@test.com%'`

Comment: Also, since this appears to be WordPress with CF7, I'd also recommend looking into `esc_like`: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8847/12496

Comment: @user3783243 work perfectly thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The object is compiled with the data type, in your case a string, and the length of the string. You could use something like:

```
'select * 
from table 
where data REGEXP concat("s:",' . mb_strlen($email) . ', ":", ?, ";")'
```

then bind the `$email`, that should get you pretty close. If an email contains special regex characters though you'll need to escape those. Alternatively a `like` could be used. Wildcards would only then need to be escaped:

```
'select * 
from table 
where data like concat("%s:",' . mb_strlen($email) . ', ":", ?, ";%")'
```

Your previous attempt also probably could have worked but you needed to fix the quoting:

```
'.*'info@test.com';s:[0-9]+:'2'.*'
```

the single quotes are for the regexp encapsulation, additionally the object construction uses double quotes, so you'd want:

```
'.*"info@test.com";s:[0-9]+:"2".*'
```

If `s:5:"email";s:` is always preceding you also could add that to make it a bit stricter.