# how can i get nested keys values inside meta_query wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

i have an meta_key 'reviewer_for_post' which includes 'reviewer_id' as an array key but how can i get it's value inside meta_query
Here what i want to do

```
'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'reviewer_for_post[reviewer_id]',
                'value'   => $user_editor->ID,
                'compare' => '='
            ),
        ),
```

i want to compare [reviewer_id](which is inside 'reviewer_for_post' key) value with $user_editor->ID value

Comment: So if `$user_editor->ID` was `5`, you are trying to look for posts that have the key `reviewer_for_post[5]` set, is that what you mean? Then insert the user id into the key, remove `value`, and use `EXISTS` as the comparison operator.

Comment: @CBroe actually, i want to compare 'reviewer_id' value with '$user_editor->ID' and 'reviewer_id' is inside another key called 'reviewer_for_post' which is an array.

Comment: I can't tell what you mean by that. Can you please show how those meta data records actually look in the database?

Comment: @CBroe here
meta_key = 'reviewer_for_post'
meta_value = 'a:4:{s:11:"reviewer_id";s:2:"56";s:13:"reviewer_name";s:12:"Michal Aibin";s:12:}'

Comment: Okay, so your key name is _not_ `reviewer_for_post[reviewer_id]`, but just `reviewer_for_post`. The value appears to be an array stored in PHP's `serialize` format (although the given example seems to be missing something, can't be unserialized.) There is no direct way to search for specific "entries" within this text value - you will have to use the LIKE operator, and search for values that contain `%s:11:"reviewer_id";s:2:"56"%` In place of the `56` you will have to insert your reviewer ID, and the 2 in `s:2` before that needs to be replaced with the number of digits the ID has.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK SQL does not support casting as an array or comparing values in the array (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116419/mysql-select-query-within-a-serialized-array)). What you can do though, is get as narrow a result as possible with SQL, and then use PHP to narrow down further (untested):

```php
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array( array(
        'key'     => 'reviewer_for_post',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ) ),
);

foreach ( $query->posts as $i => $post ) {
    $reviewer = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'reviewer_for_post', true );

    if ( is_array( $reviewer ) && ! empty( $reviewer['reviewer_id'] ) && 5 === $reviewer['reviewer_id'] ) {
        continue;
    }

    unset( $query->posts[ $i ] );
}
```

You can also use a `LIKE` comparison, but as mentioned in the other question, this is unstable and susceptible to instability.